# mingw compiler errors

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, mingw

First attempt at compiling some code without using Visual Studio. Installed mingw and set the environment path variable. Then tried to compile this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
typedef std::vector<int> Container;
typedef std::vector<int>size_type size;
typedef std::vector<int>iterator iter;

Container container; 

for (size i = 0; i != 1000000; ++i) {
container.push_back(i);
}

for (iter i = container.begin(); i != container.end(); ++i) {
std::cout << *i << " " << std::endl;
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

By opening up a cmd shell, going to directory of single source file and typing:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

But i get a lot of error messages as follows:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:35: error: expected initializer before 'size'
main.cpp:7:34: error: expected initializer before 'iter'
main.cpp:11:6: error: 'size' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:11:11: error: expected ';' before 'i'
main.cpp:11:18: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:15:6: error: 'iter' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:15:11: error: expected ';' before 'i'
main.cpp:15:34: error: 'i' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:19:15: error: 'system' was not declared in this scope
```

Am i missing something painfully obvious here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef std::vector<int>size_type size;
typedef std::vector<int>iterator iter;
```

Turn it into:

```
typedef std::vector<int>::size_type size;
typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. However i still get: main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:19:15: error: 'system' was not declared in this scope

Comment: Well, `system()` is a posix function, and you are developing on windows. You must find another way to pause the program, such as waiting for any key being pressed using `std::cin`.

Comment: Thanks... compiles now :) Wrote it in notepad c++ whereas normally i guess visual studio would have pointed out the problem with ::.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing :: operator between the vector definition and size_type (and iterator after it).

Answer (score 0):

`typedef std::vector<int>::size_type` should be `typedef std::vector<int>::size_type size;` etc.